# Livevalidation: don't validate depending on default value

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, if-statement, validation

I am trying to validate my form inputs with [livevalidation](http://livevalidation.com/examples)

In my html, I have this input field:

```
<input type="text" name="size" size="4" value="" />
```

The input above is a optional input on my form and I was wondering if there was a way to skip validation if the value was left empty and once a user types something in there, it would validate.

Also, let say if there was a default value to begin with,

```
<input type="text" name="size" size="4" value="Put Size Here" />
```

If the default value is 'Put Size Here', ignore validation and when anything other than 'Put Size Here' is inputted, validate.

I've looked at the presence option from the link above but it's not what I am looking for exactly. Is it possible to do this with livevalidation or is there another jQuery validation plugin that I could use to achieve this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Have you tried using the Inclusion? [Livevalidation Inclusion](http://livevalidation.com/examples#exampleInclusion), you can try setting the empty value as included.

---

HTML

```
<input id="size" name="size" value="Put Size here" />
```

Javascript

```
var sizeValidator= new LiveValidation('size');
size.add( Validate.Inclusion, { within: [ 'Put size here' , 'whatever', 'arbitrary' ] } );
```

Comment: I've looked at the example, though I am not entirely sure How i would go about setting it to look at the value field, could out maybe give me an example of the code with my example?

Comment: thanks for the code but in that case, the validation checks to see if the value IS 'Put size here', if not it fails to validate

Comment: You can add more valid values in the `within:[]` array I believe. Here's more documentation, more explicit: [Validate Inclusion](http://livevalidation.com/documentation#ValidateInclusion)